# Does Elixir provide a function out-of-the-box to infer a submodule name?

Tags: elixir

This code works as expected:

```
defmodule Module.Tools do
  def add_path(module, suffix) do
    (String.Chars.to_string(module) <> "." <> suffix) |> String.to_existing_atom
  end
end
```

It is just an example (no guards, no matching... you understand). I can use this to autodiscover *submodules* (even when such thing like a submodule does not properly exist, one can consider `A.B` to be a submodule of `A`). I can use this function like this:

```
scoring_submodule = Module.Tools.add_path(base_module, "Scoring")
scoring_submodule.calculate(...)
```

My question is: **Does Elixir provide one function like this out-of-the-box?**

Comment: _Sidenote:_ `String.Chars` above is redundant. [`Kernel.to_string/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#to_string/1) effectively wraps this behaviour, so that `to_string(module)` is enough.

Comment: I'm curious--what's your use case?

Comment: My use case is to autodiscover stuff inside modules I'd specify. This one is for linking different rule sets on game backends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [`Module.concat`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Module.html#concat/1) takes either a list of atoms or two atoms and concatenates them:

```
iex(1)> Module.concat(String, Chars).to_string(123)
"123"
iex(2)> Module.concat([String, Chars]).to_string(123)
"123"
```